# Why does display: table-cell; hide other elements with media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I started to work on a section of icons for my current project.

**The problem is** when I use `display: table-cell;` and change the three `.icon` styles with a media query to `width: 100%;` instead of `32%`. The other two vanish while the first one still displays.

**I figured out** how to solve this by changing it to `display: block;` but I am a little confused to why the two other divs vanish.

Here is their css:

```
.icon {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 32%;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
```

Also, here is a fiddle: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_JM/EqpLS/2/)

Any ideas of what is going on here? Does `table-cell` have to align horizontally and not break down below? When  I inspect them in the console it says the first one has a width of 500ish pixels while the other two are 0.

Comment: @Adrift Sadly that does not help. When on a mobile device I want them to take up 100% of the width while the others with drop down below each other. Since the screen is a lot less wide, I'm going from 3 columns to 1.

Comment: @Adrift You're a living CSS Hero :)

Comment: Exactly, that is how I fixed the problem originally by changing it to display block. I was just worried it would mess us any horizontal alignment. At least it doesn't but why does it do this? The best idea I can think of is tables won't break each cell to go under. I stay far away from tables so they are slightly new to me.

Comment: @Adrift I am going to enjoy a nice read, thanks for your help!

Comment: @Adrift No worries, sorry my question was misleading. :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The table layout seems to be breaking at that width, another solution would be to set the `display` property of `.icon` to be `table-row` in your media call. That makes it interpret the div as a row instead of a cell within a row, and stacks them vertically.

Here's a *[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EqpLS/5/)*

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    .icon {
    width: 100%;
    display: table-row;
    }
}
```

To be honest I'm not sure at this point why the table-layout is breaking with your code, but I can explain why the above fiddle works, so I guess this is a workaround and not a fix.

Comment: Thank you for your time. This does work great! the only problem is the hover state. It seems to activate only one of them but can be activated by any of the divs.

Comment: It's because `display: table-row` essentially negates `position: relative`, so `.iconInfo` is now being positioned absolutely in relation to the `.chat-icons`. They also have `height: 100%`, so they take up the entire div. They are stacked in order of appearance, so the last one gets stacked on top, and since it's inside the third row, that's the one getting the hover effect.

Answer (score 1):

`display: table-row` negates `position: relative`, so `.iconInfo` will now be positioned in relation to `.chat-icons`. Since `.iconInfo` have a height of 100%, they will take up the entire div. They'll also be stacked in the order they are in the html, so the bottom `.iconInfo` is on top, which is why that image is always activated on hover.

This feels kind of hacky because I'm using a number that just "looks right", but here you go. I also had to change the background on `.icon` instead of `.iconInfo` because of the change in positioning:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EqpLS/7/)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
.icon {
    display: table-row;
}
.icon:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.iconInfo {
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
    margin-top: -20%;
}
}
```

There may be some styling tweaks, but this gets you what you want (I think).